# When to use OR and when to use AND in java

Tags: java

I'm remediating some deference and redundant null findings and am just curious when someone should use an AND or an OR in a if statement.

One of the findings is at this if statement

```
String firstName = db.getString("FIRST_NAME");
if(!((firstName == null) || firstName.equals(""))){
...
}
```

Is using an OR or and AND (`if(firstName != null && !firstName.equals(""))){}`) more efficient? Or is it usually just a personal preference?

Also if someone could point out how that line has dereference that would be nice too

Comment: The `&&` is definitely easier to read.

Comment: It's just a personal preference (I prefer the latter). What do you mean by "deference"?

Comment: Both are short circuit. So it should not have a sensitive difference in terms of execution time.  The latter is indeed clearer.

Comment: Mathematical logic (very basic) says that **every** logical expression could be written using *only* **AND** and **OR**. What you prefer to use, just use it.

Comment: @shmosel sorry typeo , should be dereference

Answer (score 4):

This is a micro-optimization that will have no effect on your code performance. JVM might do various optimizations with your code during runtime due to JIT e.g. inline the method. You should prefer whichever you find more readable, could be something like `StringUtils.isNotEmpty`.

The variable `db` implies that you are accessing the database which is orders of magnitude more expensive than simple comparisons. More or less:

```
Latency Comparison Numbers
--------------------------
L1 cache reference                           0.5 ns
Branch mispredict                            5   ns
L2 cache reference                           7   ns                      14x L1 cache
Mutex lock/unlock                           25   ns
Main memory reference                      100   ns                      20x L2 cache, 200x L1 cache
Compress 1K bytes with Zippy             3,000   ns        3 us
Send 1K bytes over 1 Gbps network       10,000   ns       10 us
Read 4K randomly from SSD*             150,000   ns      150 us          ~1GB/sec SSD
Read 1 MB sequentially from memory     250,000   ns      250 us
Round trip within same datacenter      500,000   ns      500 us
Read 1 MB sequentially from SSD*     1,000,000   ns    1,000 us    1 ms  ~1GB/sec SSD, 4X memory
Disk seek                           10,000,000   ns   10,000 us   10 ms  20x datacenter roundtrip
Read 1 MB sequentially from disk    20,000,000   ns   20,000 us   20 ms  80x memory, 20X SSD
Send packet CA->Netherlands->CA    150,000,000   ns  150,000 us  150 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

Personal preference.  How these 2 statements are translated into byte code and executed in the runtime environment are subject to change.  Any performance difference you would get will likely be negligible.

You didn't ask this directly, but this is an example of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Engineering).